# ILPs with square constraint matrix

Tags: linear-programming, combinatorial-optimization, integer-programming

Given the Integer Linear Programming ($\text{ILP}$) problem

\begin{array}{ll}
\text{minimize}  & c^T x \\
\text{subject to}& \mathbf{A}^T x \ge b \\
\text{where}&c,x,b\in\mathbb{N}_0^n,\\ &\mathbf{A}\in\left(\mathbb{R}_0^+\right)^{n\times n},\, \text{det}(\mathbf{A})\gt 0
\end{array}

**Question:**

> under which additional conditions on $c,b,\mathbf{A}$ is
> $x=\lceil\mathbf{A}^{-1}b\rceil$ the optimal solution?

for vectors comparison operators and ceiling operator are to be taken element-wise.

Comment: @MaxAlekseyev I wanted to rule out negative entries in $\mathbf{A}$; I will edit the question